# after power cut - fuses all on and no power? (to pool filter)

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

We had a power cut last night due to a thunderstrom and this morning our pool filter wouldn't turn on.

I checked all fuses in the fuse box, and everything appears to be switched on.

I have a continuity tester that shows no electric getting to the box with the pool filter timer.... but i don't see any fuses or anything on the actual pool filter.

I'm thinking if there was water (from last nights storm) that somehow had gotten into the electrical box next to the filter it would still have power from the continuity tester; leading me to believe it's a fuse issue.  But again, no out-door fuse to be found.

Any ideas on what else it may be?  I'd hate to call the electrician and find out there was a fuse i didn't know about somewhere.

any tips appreciated,

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out we had just bought this house a month ago, so it  may be a hidden fuse out doors somewhere i don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when breakers trip, they can look like they're still on.  Try turning it off, then on again.

There may be a fused disconnect, which is just a metal box with a door, with a little handle thing inside. Pulling the handle thing out, cuts power to the fuses.  Then you'll have to remove a cover plate, to gain access the fuses.

Without seeing the equipment, it's difficult to provide an accurate answer.  If you post some photos, we might be able to help.